# lsyncd include specific files exclude rest

Tags: ssh, unix, lsyncd

I am using lsyncd version 2.2.2.  here is my current code.

```
settings {
 logfile = "/etc/lsyncd.log",
 statusFile = "/etc/lsyncd.status",
 insist = true,
}

sync { 
default.rsyncssh, 
source = "/home/abc/public_html/course/testcgi/adminfiles", 
host = "xxx.xx.xxx.xxx, 
targetdir = "/home/abc/public_html/course/testcgi/adminfiles", 
delay = 0, 
exclude = { '*'  }, 

rsync = { 
perms = true, 
owner = true, 
} 
}
```

As the code stands above it will and does exclude all files.  Now I want to include specific file names.  I have tried

```
include = { '*'  } 
include-from = { '*'  }
```

but neither is working.

Is this not possible to do?

Thanks.

Comment: I suspect your config file does not actually work with all those backslashes you have put in. You should try removing them.

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned this.  the backslashes are not in my actual code. for some reason the only way to get a return carriage in this post i had to use the backslash.  i have removed the backslashes.  But that was not the issue with the code.  still need help please.